# How to combine time and at command on ubuntu?

Tags: bash, at-command

I have tried to combine time and at but it doesn't seem to be something that i wanted.

```
time at now +2 min -f ./script.sh
```

I wanted to know the script execution time.
EDIT: I'm trying to run a normal `time ./script.sh` with the time output, but i want them to be running at ex:14:02 or like 2 mins from now. Because i'm trying to compare two script execution time on a different machine. And i need to run them at the same time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. Since the command you tried doesn't work, it is impossible to guess what you want it to do. How should these be combined? Do you want to run a command at a specific time? Do you want to see how much time a command takes?

Comment: If you want to run a command a specific amount of time in the future, use `sleep`, i.e, `sleep 120 && command` will wait 2 minutes before running `command`. If you want to run something at a specific time, `chron` may the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to time the script, not the `at` command. Do something like:

```
echo "/usr/bin/time -o /tmp/script-time ./script.sh" | at now +2 min
```

And the output of `time` will be saved to `/tmp/script-time`.